# Products with included tax price are not displayed right

Tags: magento-1.9, tax, shipping-tax

As mentioned in the title i have set a tax rate at 23% and through the tax calculation i have chosen the product prices to include tax. My problem is that when i am going to the cart the tax is calculated again and added to total once more. That makes my product to have double tax.
How can this be solved?

Comment: Googling for `magento tax applied twice` is giving some promising results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer, in shipping methods there was united states as default, so i changed to my own country and the tax started to be calculated normally.